# Where can i get latest electronic seminar topics?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet

Hi i would like to know a website that discusses the latest technology in the field of electronics (mosfet, microcontroller etc).

I have to give a technical seminar on electronics and communication stream.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [EE Times](http://www.electronics-eetimes.com/).
This has the latest reports, information, technical papers, newsletters, etc from all areas of the electronics industry.

Comment: "free registration required" btw.